# Git pull on cronjob

Tags: linux, git

I'm having trouble doing a `git pull` command from remote repository in a cronjob. I'm using linux and my crontab looks like this:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /var/www/html && git pull origin master && chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/html/* >/dev/null 2>&1
```

When I do a `tail -f /var/log/syslog` I can see the cronjob is running but it's not pulling any new files. And when I run the command manually it works with no problem.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: The first rule of troubleshooting: don't discard output. Instead redirect it to e.g. a file under `/tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

- use `git -C /var/www/html` to omit the `cd`
- Did you use the crontab for the right user?